# What went wrong with events search? "Counted" link gives error... How to fix it?

Tags: civievent, search, search-results

I am on civicrm 4.6.5. From a Event Dashboard when I select the "Counted" link to see the list of participants, "DB Error: syntax error" appears on the screen. And from civicrm log I get the following message. So far it was working perfectly fine. I am not sure what went wrong!!! Can anyone help please?

```
Jul 21 12:30:53  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND
                                                        contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant ON civicrm_participant.contact_id = contact_a.id  INNER JOIN civicrm_event ON civicrm_participant.event_id = civicrm_event.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_event_type ON (option_group_event_type.name = 'event_type') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value event_type ON (civicrm_event.event_type_id = event_type.value AND option_group_event_type.id = event_type.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_discount discount ON ( civicrm_participant.discount_id = discount.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group discount_name ON ( discount_name.id = discount.price_set_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_participant_role ON (option_group_participant_role.name = 'participant_role') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value participant_role ON (civicrm_participant.role_id = participant_role.value
                               AND option_group_participant_role.id = participant_role.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant_status_type participant_status ON (civicrm_participant.status_id = participant_status.id)  WHERE  ( civicrm_event.id = 15 AND civicrm_participant.status_id 0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'  AND civicrm_participant.is_test = 0 )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)     [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:' at line 3]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND
                                                        contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant ON civicrm_participant.contact_id = contact_a.id  INNER JOIN civicrm_event ON civicrm_participant.event_id = civicrm_event.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_event_type ON (option_group_event_type.name = 'event_type') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value event_type ON (civicrm_event.event_type_id = event_type.value AND option_group_event_type.id = event_type.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_discount discount ON ( civicrm_participant.discount_id = discount.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group discount_name ON ( discount_name.id = discount.price_set_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_participant_role ON (option_group_participant_role.name = 'participant_role') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value participant_role ON (civicrm_participant.role_id = participant_role.value
                               AND option_group_participant_role.id = participant_role.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant_status_type participant_status ON (civicrm_participant.status_id = participant_status.id)  WHERE  ( civicrm_event.id = 15 AND civicrm_participant.status_id 0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'  AND civicrm_participant.is_test = 0 )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)     [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:' at line 3]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND
                                                        contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant ON civicrm_participant.contact_id = contact_a.id  INNER JOIN civicrm_event ON civicrm_participant.event_id = civicrm_event.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_event_type ON (option_group_event_type.name = 'event_type') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value event_type ON (civicrm_event.event_type_id = event_type.value AND option_group_event_type.id = event_type.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_discount discount ON ( civicrm_participant.discount_id = discount.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group discount_name ON ( discount_name.id = discount.price_set_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_participant_role ON (option_group_participant_role.name = 'participant_role') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value participant_role ON (civicrm_participant.role_id = participant_role.value
                               AND option_group_participant_role.id = participant_role.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant_status_type participant_status ON (civicrm_participant.status_id = participant_status.id)  WHERE  ( civicrm_event.id = 15 AND civicrm_participant.status_id 0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'  AND civicrm_participant.is_test = 0 )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)     [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 AND  civicrm_participant.role_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:' at line 3]"]
)


Jul 21 12:30:53  [info] $backTrace = #0 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(235): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#4 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#5 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#7 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#9 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#10 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#11 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#12 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1221): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", TRUE)
#13 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4609): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#14 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Selector/Search.php(288): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(0, 0, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NULL)
#15 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(233): CRM_Event_Selector_Search->getTotalCount(4, NULL)
#16 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(336): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->__construct(Object(CRM_Event_Selector_Search), NULL, NULL, 4, Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), 1, NULL)
#17 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(124): CRM_Event_Form_Search->postProcess()
#18 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Event_Form_Search->preProcess()
#19 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#20 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
#21 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
#22 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#23 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#24 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#25 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#26 /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#27 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "search")
#28 /srv/www/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#29 /srv/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced in 4.6.5. My guess is 4.6.6 will be out pretty quickly as a result!

Check here if you want to jump in & patch your install

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16858